Issue with setuptools in build environment while installing dj-rest-auth in Django project
I am working on a Django REST Framework / React JS project. I developed this application using Gitpod and now I'm trying to set it up on my local machine using VS Code on Windows. I am encountering an issue when trying to install my project's dependencies from requirements.txt.
Problem:
When running pip install -r requirements.txt, I encounter the following error related to setuptools while trying to install dj-rest-auth:
Collecting dj-rest-auth==2.1.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached dj-rest-auth-2.1.9.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

What I have tried so far:

Installing Visual C++ Build Tools:

Downloaded and installed the latest version with C++ build tools.


Creating a new virtual environment
pip install --upgrade pip and pip install setuptools==57.5.0 wheel==0.36.2
Adding setuptools to requirements.txt (This is how my requirements.txt look like) :

asgiref==3.7.2
black==23.12.1
click==8.1.7
cloudinary==1.37.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-rest-auth==2.1.9
Django==3.2
django-allauth==0.44.0
django-cloudinary-storage==0.3.0
django-cors-headers==4.3.1
django-filter==23.5
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.3.1
gunicorn==21.2.0
oauthlib==3.2.2
pathspec==0.12.1
Pillow==10.1.0
psycopg2==2.9.9
PyJWT==2.8.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2023.3.post1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.4
whitenoise==6.4.0
setuptools==57.5.0
wheel==0.36.2


I solved it. I had Python 3.9.17 installed in GitPod, and Python 3.12.2 in venv.
I installed 3.9.13 (since 3.9.17 wasn't available), than I pip install setuptools==58.0.4   and then pip install -r requirements.txt
